# C : text file, string comparison and so on

Tags: c, arrays, string, file, string-comparison

first of all here's a link to my code : http://codepad.org/u68QnKPp

To describe briefly what my code does : It takes a sequence of exactly 5 letters at execution (for instance : `./anagramme p a n n e`) and goes through a lot including a word list creation, a comparison with a static dictionary (fr5.txt) to see if any word created (anagrams) exists in french and then should display those words (if they exist).

The problem appears at line 191 where the comparison (using streq) fails even if both strings are equal (hints the little indented tryna debug part) and thus never matches any word even if it encounters a correct one (unless you code it directly into the if condition obviously ... cf commented part).

The `streq()` function seems to function *clap clap* since commented part works well when non commented.

My question is : What I did wrong in the string comparison/pointers manipulation and how should I solve it ?

[EDIT : show code of problem (newest version will always be the above link)]

```
    time_t start,end;
    float elapsed;
        /**looping through dictionnary and comparing to words found**/
    start=clock();
    for(int i=0 ; i<res_len ; i++){
        fichier f = fopen("fr5.txt","r");
        if(f==NULL)exit(-1);
        if(verbose){echo("file opened for loop\n");}
        char* curr_loop_word = (char*)malloc(6 * sizeof(char));
        strcpy(curr_loop_word,iter[i]);
        for(int j=0 ; j<dico_nb_ligne ; j++){
            if(verbose)echo("browsing dictionnary");
            char* curr =(char*)malloc(6 * sizeof(char)) ;
            //strcpy(curr, fgetl(f));
            size_t len=5;
            ssize_t x = getline(&curr,&len,f);

                char* tst = (char*)malloc(6 * sizeof(char));
                char* test = (char*)malloc(6 * sizeof(char));
                for(int i=0 ; i<5 ; i++){
                    tst[i]=curr[i];
                    test[i]=curr_loop_word[i];
                }
                tst[5]='_';
                test[5]='_';
                strcpy(curr,tst);
                free(tst);
                strcpy(curr_loop_word,test);
                free(test);

            if(x==-1)exit((int)x);
            if(verbose)printf("size : %zu",x);
            if(verbose)printf("current dictionnary word : %s\n",curr);

            if(streq(curr,curr_loop_word)/* || streq(curr,"panne_")*/){//problem occurs here
                if(verbose)echo("found one :\n");
                strcpy(mots[mots_len],curr);
                mots_len+=1;
                if(verbose){
                    printf("correct word found : %s\n",curr);
                }
                break;
            }

        }
        fclose(f);
        if(verbose){echo("file closed after loop\n");}
    }
    end=clock();
    elapsed = (float)(end-start)/(float)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
```

[/EDIT]

PS:
I use `getline()` because each word is on a separate line in the file (words are already sorted out to only contain 5 letter words).

PS2:
I hope you don't mind the fancy indentation for functions prior to `main()` it was purely to be clear what is what when I browse the code without to put a marker on main.

PS3:
I hope my question/problem is clear if not tell me what is not and I'll edit it.

PS4:
Maybe a good solution would be to switch to C++ to avoid at least one level of pointers ?

Comment: I think it might be helpful if you add a minimal piece of code showing your problem directly to your post.

Comment: @Vivick: Don't change the code in your question like that when it's been answered, existing answers become nonsense when you do that.

Answer (score 1):

Here (style and indentation improved):

```
char * curr = malloc(6);
size_t len = 5;
ssize_t x = getline(&curr, &len, f);

char * tst = malloc(6);
char * test = malloc(6);
for ( int i = 0; i < 5; ++i ) {
    tst[i] = curr[i];
    test[i] = curr_loop_word[i];
}

tst[5] = '_';
test[5] = '_';

strcpy(curr, tst);
free(tst);

strcpy(curr_loop_word, test);
free(test);
```

you begin with `curr`, a 6 character dynamically allocated array that you provide to `getline()` to store a 5 character string. OK so far, except you never check if `getline()` actually got 5 characters, and you should.

What you seem to want to do is write those 5 characters plus an underscore into `tst`. But you also make `tst` 6 characters long, and you need seven characters for your six plus the terminating null character. Then, on top of that, you don't actually write the terminal null character, so your strings are not terminated, and your `strcpy()` calls are going to run over the end of your arrays, and any following `strcmp()` calls are going to fail equally miserably.

So, you need to allocate 7 bytes here, and you need to write the terminating null to both strings.

A small number of other points which jump out from your code:

- Don't cast the return value from `malloc()` - it's unnecessary in C, and generally considered bad style
- `sizeof(char)` is 1 by definition, so don't use it
- Nothing but trouble can come from `typedef`ing `FILE *` in this manner - just use `FILE *`
- Instead of defining your `echo()` function, you can just use the standard `puts()`
- In your `notEOF()` function, on systems where `char` is unsigned, `x == EOF` is not going to work. `getchar()` returns `int`, not `char`, so your `notEOF()` function should take an `int` argument, not a `char` argument.
- There is no point to use `malloc()` to allocate, time and time again, an array of a small size known at compile time. Just use `char tst[6];`, or `char tst[7];` when you fix it. There's certainly no need to `malloc()` and `free()` them over and over again on each iteration through your loop.
- In any case, `malloc()` can fail, and you never check for this. You should.
- Your big `main()` function is crying out to be broken up into smaller ones which can be tested and debugged separately.
- On that same subject, it's hard to understand why you have so many global variables for such a short program, when all of them are only ever used in one function
- Try to remember that your keyboard has a space bar

EDIT: Here's a sensible way to do it, using an actual data structure suitable for the problem, and with the logic broken out appropriately into separate functions. It ends up with a bit more code than your example, but what you spend in writing a bit more code you save in the number of hours you're not spending staring at your screen wondering why it's not working. In particular, look at the main file, `dictlist.c` and notice how many times we:

- call `malloc()` - never
- compare one string to another - once, when checking the command line arguments
- copy a string - never
- directly set a character in a string, or manually add a terminating null character to a string - once, when removing the new line character from file input
- increment a counter - never, other than `for` loop indices
- sort data - never

Every time we don't do one of these things while writing our program's main logic is one time we're guaranteed to not make a mistake while doing it.

dictfind.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "wordlist.h"
#include "logging.h"

#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 64


/*
 * Returns a word list made from entries in a dictionary file
 */

WordList get_dictionary(void)
{
    WordList dict = wordlist_create();

    FILE * fp = fopen("dictionary.txt", "r");
    if ( !fp ) {
        perror("couldn't open dictionary for reading");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char buffer[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
    while ( fgets(buffer, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, fp) ) {
        size_t len = strlen(buffer);
        if ( len > 0 && buffer[len - 1] == '\n' ) {
            buffer[len - 1] = 0;
        }
        wordlist_add(dict, buffer);
    }

    if ( fclose(fp) != 0 ) {
        perror("couldn't close dictionary file");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    log_msg("Read %zu words into dictionary.\n", wordlist_length(dict));

    return dict;
}


/*
 * Returns true if none of the arguments equal each other
 */

bool no_dups(size_t i, size_t j, size_t k, size_t l, size_t m)
{
    return i != j && i != k && i != l && i != m &&
           j != k && j != l && j != m && k != l &&
           k != m && l != m;
}


/*
 * Returns a list of words of all combinations of the five
 * letter string provided.
 */

WordList make_words(char * letters)
{
    WordList words = wordlist_create();

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < 5; ++i ) {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < 5; ++j ) {
            for ( size_t k = 0; k < 5; ++k ) {
                for ( size_t l = 0; l < 5; ++l ) {
                    for ( size_t m = 0; m < 5; ++m ) {
                        if ( no_dups(i, j, k, l, m) ) {
                            char new_word[] = {letters[i], letters[j],
                                letters[k], letters[l], letters[m], 0};
                            wordlist_add_unique(words, new_word);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    log_msg("Made %zu words from input.\n", wordlist_length(words));

    return words;
}


/*
 * Returns a list of dictionary matches from a list of candidate words
 */

WordList get_matches(WordList dict, WordList words)
{
    WordList matches = wordlist_create();

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < wordlist_length(words); ++i ) {
        char * word = wordlist_word(words, i);
        if ( wordlist_contains(dict, word) ) {
            wordlist_add(matches, word);
            log_msg("Adding found match: %s\n", word);
        }
    }

    return matches;
}


/*
 * Main function
 */

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    if ( argc == 7 && strcmp(argv[6], "-v") == 0 ) {
        logging_enable(true);
    }
    else if ( argc != 6 ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: dictfind a b c d e [-v]\n");
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }

    char letters[5] = {argv[1][0], argv[2][0], argv[3][0],
                       argv[4][0], argv[5][0]};

    WordList dict = get_dictionary();
    WordList words = make_words(letters);
    WordList matches = get_matches(dict, words);

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < wordlist_length(matches); ++i ) {
        printf("Match found: %s\n", wordlist_word(matches, i));
    }

    wordlist_destroy(dict);
    wordlist_destroy(words);
    wordlist_destroy(matches);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

wordlist.h:

```
#ifndef WORD_LIST_H
#define WORD_LIST_H

#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct wordlist * WordList;

WordList wordlist_create(void);
void wordlist_destroy(WordList list);
void wordlist_add(WordList list, char * word);
void wordlist_add_unique(WordList list, char * word);
char * wordlist_word(WordList list, size_t index);
int wordlist_find(WordList list, char * word);
bool wordlist_contains(WordList list, char * word);
size_t wordlist_length(WordList list);

#endif
```

wordlist.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "wordlist.h"

#define INITIAL_LIST_CAPACITY 16

struct wordlist {
    size_t length;
    size_t capacity;
    char ** words;
};

WordList wordlist_create(void)
{
    struct wordlist * new_list = malloc(sizeof *new_list);
    if ( !new_list ) {
        perror("couldn't allocate memory for word list");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char ** new_words = malloc(INITIAL_LIST_CAPACITY * sizeof(*new_words));
    if ( !new_words ) {
        perror("couldn't allocate memory for words");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    new_list->length = 0;
    new_list->capacity = INITIAL_LIST_CAPACITY;
    new_list->words = new_words;

    return new_list;
}

void wordlist_destroy(WordList list)
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < list->length; ++i ) {
        free(list->words[i]);
    }
    free(list->words);
    free(list);
}

void wordlist_add(WordList list, char * word)
{
    if ( list->length == list->capacity ) {
        list->capacity *= 2;
        char ** new_words = realloc(list->words,
                                    list->capacity * sizeof *new_words);
        if ( !new_words ) {
            perror("couldn't reallocate memory for word list");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        list->words = new_words;
    }

    char * new_word = malloc(strlen(word) + 1);
    if ( !new_word ) {
        perror("couldn't allocate memory for new word");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    strcpy(new_word, word);
    list->words[list->length++] = new_word;
}

void wordlist_add_unique(WordList list, char * word)
{
    if ( wordlist_find(list, word) == -1 ) {
        wordlist_add(list, word);
    }
}

char * wordlist_word(WordList list, size_t index)
{
    if ( index >= list->length ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "word list accessed out of bounds\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return list->words[index];
}

int wordlist_find(WordList list, char * word)
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < list->length; ++i ) {
        if ( strcmp(list->words[i], word) == 0 ) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

bool wordlist_contains(WordList list, char * word)
{
    return wordlist_find(list, word) != -1;
}

size_t wordlist_length(WordList list)
{
    return list->length;
}
```

logging.h:

```
#ifndef LOGGING_H
#define LOGGING_H

#include <stdbool.h>

void logging_enable(bool enabled);
void log_msg(char * fmt, ...);

#endif
```

logging.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include "logging.h"

static bool logging_enabled = false;

void logging_enable(bool enabled)
{
    logging_enabled = enabled;
}

void log_msg(char * fmt, ...)
{
    if ( logging_enabled ) {
        va_list ap;
        va_start(ap, fmt);
        vfprintf(stderr, fmt, ap);
        va_end(ap);
    }
}
```

dictionary.txt:

```
apple
plate
words
finds
trunk
poked
tiger
horse
spill
horns
stuff
boxed
fried
biter
sword
tribe
shore
hoser
pills
fired
```

Makefile:

```
dictfind: dictfind.o wordlist.o logging.o
    cc -o dictfind dictfind.o wordlist.o logging.o

dictfind.o: dictfind.c wordlist.h logging.h
    cc -o dictfind.o dictfind.c -c -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall

wordlist.o: wordlist.c wordlist.h
    cc -o wordlist.o wordlist.c -c -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall

logging.o: logging.c logging.h
    cc -o logging.o logging.c -c -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall

clean:
    rm -f dictfind dictfind.o wordlist.o logging.o
```

with sample output:

```
paul@thoth:~/src/sandbox/dictfind$ make
cc -o dictfind.o dictfind.c -c -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall
cc -o wordlist.o wordlist.c -c -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall
cc -o logging.o logging.c -c -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall
cc -o dictfind dictfind.o wordlist.o logging.o
paul@thoth:~/src/sandbox/dictfind$ ./dictfind b r i t e
Match found: biter
Match found: tribe
paul@thoth:~/src/sandbox/dictfind$ ./dictfind d w s r o -v
Read 20 words into dictionary.
Made 120 words from input.
Adding found match: words
Adding found match: sword
Match found: words
Match found: sword
paul@thoth:~/src/sandbox/dictfind$ ./dictfind b i t e s
paul@thoth:~/src/sandbox/dictfind$ ./dictfind f t u s f -v
Read 20 words into dictionary.
Made 60 words from input.
Adding found match: stuff
Match found: stuff
paul@thoth:~/src/sandbox/dictfind$ ./dictfind a a a a h -v
Read 20 words into dictionary.
Made 5 words from input.
paul@thoth:~/src/sandbox/dictfind$
```

Comment: To follow your answer I reduce the amount of malloc'd pointer and replace as much as I could think of with arrays, I made sure to exit program if any pointer is nil, I made sure to have my '\0' and the right amount of characters on each array.

This surely made things a lot more safe and correct but it still haven't solve the comparison issue that still happens after mods :/.

Comment: @Vivick: `iter[wc]=word;` is also obviously wrong, as you're storing a pointer to an array which is about to go out of scope and cease to exist. You should be using `strcpy()` to copy strings.

Answer (score 0):

First of all thanks you all for your very helpful answers.
I've found my crucial mistake thanks to Paul Griffiths :

I copied paste his work to try it out and I was astonished to see no results and in a flash I remembered one stupid little thing : I'm on windows.
Which means a shit ton of \r in my file which causes the program to never find a correct match.
Therefore I just "dos2unix f5.txt" on babun and tada problem solved

Now that I found my error, I think I'll rewrite the whole program to C++ (easier for me) using (for sure) objects and maybe build side libraries just like Paul did.

Again thanks for the answers ;).

Remember kids : windows text editing -> \r